# How do I determine the name of the client machine logged into Remote Destop?

Tags: winapi, remote-desktop

I can use GetSystemMetrics(SM_REMOTESESSION) Windows API function to determine if the current user is running via Remote Desktop.  Once I've verified that, is there any way for me to determine his machine name?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

```
WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,
                           WTS_CURRENT_SESSION,
                           WTSClientName,
                           BufPtr,
                           BytesReturned);
```